# Multiprocessing starmap_async python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am learning to use multiprocessing in python and I have a question. I want to count the number of times an object (i.e. tuple of words) is in a list. I propose two options. The first using **pool.starmap_async** and the second without multiprocessing.

```
ngrams=[('review', 'productivity'), ('productivity', 'satisfaction'), ('satisfaction', 'democratic'), ('democratic', 'autocratic'), ('autocratic', 'leadership'), ('leadership', 'empirical'), ('empirical', 'literature'), ('literature', 'explore'), ('explore', 'organizational_outcome'), ('organizational_outcome', 'democratic'), ('democratic', 'leadership'), ('leadership', 'task##oriented'), ('task##oriented', 'group'), ('group', 'individual'), ('individual', 'member'), ('member', 'productivity'), ('productivity', 'satisfaction'), ('satisfaction', 'receive'), ('receive', 'attention'), ('attention', 'emphasis')]
ngrams_uniq=[('satisfaction', 'democratic'), ('organizational_outcome', 'democratic'), ('review', 'productivity'), ('democratic', 'leadership'), ('member', 'productivity'), ('receive', 'attention'), ('empirical', 'literature'), ('group', 'individual'), ('literature', 'explore'), ('democratic', 'autocratic'), ('autocratic', 'leadership'), ('attention', 'emphasis'), ('task##oriented', 'group'), ('explore', 'organizational_outcome'), ('leadership', 'task##oriented'), ('satisfaction', 'receive'), ('productivity', 'satisfaction'), ('leadership', 'empirical'), ('individual', 'member')]

def count_ngrams(gram,ngrams):
  return (gram,ngrams.count(gram))
```

##With Pool

```
print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
dict_freq_ngrams=pool.starmap_async(count_ngrams,[(gram,ngrams) for gram in ngrams_uniq]).get()
pool.close()
print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

##Without Pool

```
print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
dict_freq_ngrams=[count_ngrams(gram,ngrams) for gram in ngrams_uniq]
print(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

When I measure the execution time I always get that the second option is faster. I don't understand why that happens ... maybe I have an error but I don't know what it is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need more than trivial work to have multiprocessing pay off.  Starting a process and interprocess data transfer is expensive.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you have an error rather the overhead of copying the data to the new interpreter form multiprocessing outwais the speed gains made by paralel computation
as just starting pool takes 0.2 to 0.3 seconds on my surface

hers the code i used to test[image]

```
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import copy

ngrams=[('review', 'productivity'), ('productivity', 'satisfaction'), ('satisfaction', 'democratic'), ('democratic', 'autocratic'), ('autocratic', 'leadership'), ('leadership', 'empirical'), ('empirical', 'literature'), ('literature', 'explore'), ('explore', 'organizational_outcome'), ('organizational_outcome', 'democratic'), ('democratic', 'leadership'), ('leadership', 'task##oriented'), ('task##oriented', 'group'), ('group', 'individual'), ('individual', 'member'), ('member', 'productivity'), ('productivity', 'satisfaction'), ('satisfaction', 'receive'), ('receive', 'attention'), ('attention', 'emphasis')]*40
ngrams_uniq=[('satisfaction', 'democratic'), ('organizational_outcome', 'democratic'), ('review', 'productivity'), ('democratic', 'leadership'), ('member', 'productivity'), ('receive', 'attention'), ('empirical', 'literature'), ('group', 'individual'), ('literature', 'explore'), ('democratic', 'autocratic'), ('autocratic', 'leadership'), ('attention', 'emphasis'), ('task##oriented', 'group'), ('explore', 'organizational_outcome'), ('leadership', 'task##oriented'), ('satisfaction', 'receive'), ('productivity', 'satisfaction'), ('leadership', 'empirical'), ('individual', 'member')]
ngrams_copy=copy.copy(ngrams)

def count_ngrams(gram,ngrams):
    return (gram,ngrams.count(gram))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    std = np.array([])
    Pool= np.array([])
    for i in range(100):
        
        t = time.time()
        with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
            res=pool.starmap_async(count_ngrams,[(val, ngrams) for val in ngrams_uniq])
            dict_freq_ngrams = res.get()#(gram,ngrams) for gram in ngrams_uniq]

        Pool = np.append(Pool, np.array(time.time() - t))
        print(i)

        t = time.time()
        dict_freq_ngrams=[count_ngrams(gram,ngrams) for gram in ngrams_uniq]
        std = np.append(std, np.array(time.time() - t))
        ngrams = ngrams+ngrams_copy

    plt.plot(std)
    plt.plot(Pool)
    plt.show()
```